# Codility task 'TapeEquilibrium' performance

Tags: java, performance

I have solved first task in codility (TapeEquilibrium).

I have managed to get 50% score (100% correctness, 0% performance).

Can you give me some tips how can i increase the performance.

Link to my results and problem description are [here](https://codility.com/demo/results/demo3T2XD8-K6D/).

Code is below:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        List<Integer> splittedTape = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
            splittedTape.add(calculateDifference(i, A));
        }
        Collections.sort(splittedTape);
        return splittedTape.get(0);
    }

    private int calculateDifference(int position, int[] array){
        int sumA = 0;
        int sumB = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if (i < position){
                sumA += array[i];
            } else {
                sumB += array[i];
            }
        }
        return Math.abs(sumA - sumB);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For those note familiar with codility, could you give some context? What's the goal here?

Comment: Might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, since they focus more on working code..

Comment: Please note that you are violating the codility [terms of service](https://codility.com/terms-of-service-for-programmers) by posting this here.

Comment: @Marcin Marczyk ... u should not post the problem description out here. better provide url for the problem statement

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't quite tested the corner cases so this might not produce expected results but this is an O(N) solution for achieving what the problem is asking for.

```
class Solution {
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    int totalSum = 0;
    int firstSum = A[0];
    for(int i=1;i<A.length;i++)
     totalSum += A[i]; 

    int min = Math.abs(firstSum-totalSum);

    for(int i=1;i<A.length-1;i++) {
        firstSum+=A[i];
        totalSum-=A[i];
        if(Math.abs(firstSum-totalSum)<min) 
            min = Math.abs(firstSum-totalSum);

    }
    return min;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following java solution gives 100% with O(n) complexity.

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    int accumulator = 0;
    int originalArrayLength = A.length;
    int[] accumulatedArray = new int[originalArrayLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < originalArrayLength; i++) {
        accumulator += A[i];
        accumulatedArray[i] = accumulator;
    }

    int max = accumulatedArray[originalArrayLength - 1];
    int minAbsoluteDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < accumulatedArray.length - 1; i++) {
        int firstSum = accumulatedArray[i];
        int secondSum = max - firstSum;
        int absoluteDiff = Math.abs(firstSum - secondSum);

        if (absoluteDiff < minAbsoluteDiff) {
            minAbsoluteDiff = absoluteDiff;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code a little easier to understand:

```
class Solution {
public int solution(int[] numbersOnATape) {

    int minimalDifference = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int sumOfFirstPart = 0;
    int sumOfSecondPart = sumOfValuesInsideOfTheTap(numbersOnATape);

    for (int count = 0; count < numbersOnATape.length - 1; count++) {
        int currentNumber = numbersOnATape[count];
        int nextNumber = numbersOnATape[count + 1];
        sumOfFirstPart += currentNumber;

        int difference = Math.abs(sumOfFirstPart - sumOfSecondPart);
        if (minimalDifference > difference) {
            minimalDifference = difference;
        }
        sumOfSecondPart -= nextNumber;
    }

    return minimalDifference;
}

private int sumOfValuesInsideOfTheTap(int[] numbersOnATape) {

    int sumOfValuesInsideOfTheTap = 0;

    for (int count = 1; count < numbersOnATape.length; count++) {
        sumOfValuesInsideOfTheTap += numbersOnATape[count];
    }

    return sumOfValuesInsideOfTheTap;
}
```

}

Scores 100%

Answer (score 0):

following Swift solution gives 84%  O(n) complexity

```
func minimalDifference( A: [Int]) -> Int {

    var sum = 0;
    let originalArrayLength = A.count-1
    var sumArray = [Int]()

    for  i in 0...originalArrayLength {

        sum += A[i];
        sumArray.append(sum)
    }

    let totalSum = sumArray[originalArrayLength]
    var minDiff = Int.max

    for i in 0..<sumArray.count {

        let firstSum = sumArray[i];
        let secondSum = totalSum - firstSum
        let diff = abs(firstSum - secondSum)

        if (diff < minDiff) {

            minDiff = diff
        }
    }

    return minDiff

}
```